# TFSBuild - Saving OpenCover/ReportGenerator output for each tfs build on tfs2013

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, opencover, reportgenerator

I'm currently trying to run custom code coverage using [OpenCover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover) and to generate output in easily readable format using [Report Generator](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator). The final output of these two applications is xml files.

I am running these applications using InvokeProcess activity in build definition to get their outputs but the output are currently present only in my build controller's Build binaries folder.(ex:`C:\Builds\1\project_collection\build_definition\bin`)

I want to save these files per build in some location and to retrieve them back when needed by clicking on a hyperlink present in Build summary similar to how built-in code coverage results are displayed in tfs build summary.

I tried this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906487/display-opencover-results-in-tfs-2015-build-summary) but as you can see there is no correct answers listed there.

So how do I copy these output files to some remote location and refer them in my build summary to retrieve them?

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy outputs to some remote location is similar to copy outputs to drop folder. You can simply specify the drop location in **Build Definition--Build Defaults--Staging location**. Check the screenshot below:

[image]

2. Refer the binaries in your build summary to retrieve them, you can add a new activity “**WriteCustomSummaryInformation**” to your build process template, which has several properties that allow you create a new Section and add text to that section. Check this blog for more information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2012/06/07/tfs11-rc-simple-build-summary-customization.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As I also answered here [Display OpenCover results in TFS 2015 build Summary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906487/display-opencover-results-in-tfs-2015-build-summary/37832443#37832443), it is now possible to customize the build results in TFS 2015.

> I managed to upload the OpenCover xml result file as 'testrun-attachment' via REST-interface and got the pieces in place to show the summary values on both the build summary tab and on its own extended “build-results-view”.