# Is it possible to add custom code coverage to TFS 2015

Tags: tfs-2015, dotcover

We use TFS 2015 vNext as our build system. However we use dotCover from JetBrains as our code coverage tool. The reason we don't use the built-in TFS code coverage tool is that this requires an Enterprise licence and we only have Professional licences (and upgrading is not an option).

Is it possible to display code coverage from a different code coverage tool to be displayed on the build results page in TFS 2015 (as in the screen shot below)?

[image]

Comment: Similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906487/display-opencover-results-in-tfs-2015-build-summary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate with this question [Display OpenCover results in TFS 2015 build Summary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906487/display-opencover-results-in-tfs-2015-build-summary) .Your requirement could be achieved after **TFS2015 update2**.

> If you want to display your custom result in the build result summary,
>   seems you will have to **write your own extensions**. Help link:
>   [Overview of extensions for Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/overview)
>
> Base for this  were a lot of examples provided by MS on github:
>
> - [Visual Studio Team Services Tasks](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks)
> - [Visual Studio Team Services Sample Extensions](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples)
>
> To get a first feeling **what places on your TFS Web Portal can be
>   extended/customized** you can download and install this extension 
>   [Contributions Guide](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-samples.samples-contributions-guide)  from the *Visual Studio Marketplace*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I'm looking for.