# Need sonar analysis report in TFS portal

Tags: tfs, sonarqube

I have integrated SonarQube with TFS.I am scanning a Java project in sonarqube via TFS using commandline task. In Tool: gave the sonarscanner path. I want to display the entire sonarqube analysis report in TFS. Is there any task in TFS which will help me display the sonarqube analysis report with issues  and vulnerabilities.I want the sonar to be directly accessible through TFS once the anlaysis is done. Please help. Is this feasible?

Comment: Which kind of TFS build are you using? vNext or XAML?

Comment: I am using ant build. Is there any extension in marketplace which would help me display the entire sonar analysis report in TFS itself?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **vNext** build, you could use the  **Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner CLI Task** to analyze projects outside MSBuild such Java build technologies.

More detail steps please take a look at below link:
[Analyzing with SonarQube Extension for VSTS/TFS](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS) (*TFS2015 update3 and later*)

> **Analysis Reports**
>
> Currently, neither reports nor Pull Request analysis comments are
>   supported in this mode.

Unfortunately, the analysis reports feature is not support in this task for the integration with TFS. You could submit a uservoice to sonarqube team.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. But can i display the entire sonar analysis report on TFS portal. In Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner CLI task, it shows only if the project has passed the quality gates. Is there any Extension or can we do it by opening restapi so that we could see all the bugs, issues, vulnerabilities on TFS portal itself?

Comment: Sorry @uttarabhosale  I'm not so familiar with the SonarQube report  .What's  the format  of it ? Did the SonarQube server  will generate a file with the entire report such as a .xml file. If so you could write your own TFS extension to catch the info and display the info either in the build result page or a TFS dash board. More details you could refer the answer from *Robert* in  this question. Seems there is no existing extension in marketplace.

Comment: @uttarabhosale Sorry for the missing link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906487/display-opencover-results-in-tfs-2015-build-summary